# ios 9 app localization: Invalid path error

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I have been working on a project for a while. The app is now working, and I wanted to internationalize it. I go to project manager, info tab, and I see that "use base internationalization" is checked (Indeed, my storyboard files are located in "Base.lproj").

Under "Localizations" I can see "English - Development Language" with "2 files localized" (my LaunchScreen and Main storyboard files). So far so good.

Now, I press "+" to add a language, and select "Spanish": I get an error saying "The file path [my project path]/es.lproj/Main.strings is invalid. The expected prefix is [my project path]/Base.lproj"

The "es.lproj" is created in my project folder, but the new language does not appear in my project info tab under "Localizations." Only English is visible.

My project is under Git source control, so I am weary of manually deleting or adding things. I am also using cocoapods libraries.

I have tried to find solutions to this online, but the only one I found does not work for me. I have been tempted to uncehck "Use Base Internationalization" and then check it again, but I don't want to mess up my project (Xcode tells me those changes "cannot be undone").

Any help will be greatly apprciated!